# Opposite of itself

Tags: meaning, antonyms

I'm looking for a word that means that something is the opposite of itself.

Like wanting to be alone but being afraid of being alone.

The word sounds something similar to ignorant I think.

Comment: When you have "mixed feelings" about something, you feel partly positive and partly negative. Now, is it the opposite of **itself**? Can you show us context where the word or phrase could be used?

Comment: If you both want and not want something, you are _conflicted_.

Comment: This is a (Single) Word Request and as such requires an example sentence (preferably with a 'blank') and the tag: SWR (please read its description).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for *irreconcilable*?
You might say that your feelings are difficult to reconcile, akin to saying that you are *conflicted*, as was suggested in the comments. You might also say that you find it difficult to reconcile someone else's behavior with their words, in which case *conflicted* would not be appropriate.

If you are asking what to call a word that has opposing meanings - being it's own antonym - that word is *contronym* or *auto-antonym*.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the word **contradictory**: mutually opposed or inconsistent.

> contradiction
>
> A statement that contradicts itself, i.e., a statement that makes a
> claim that the same thing is true and that it is false at the same
> time and in the same senses of the terms. There is a contradiction in
> Clarence Page's statement that a woman should have the right to choose
> and decide for herself whether to have an abortion, and at the same
> time she should not have that right. There is a contradiction in what
> you say - she can't be both married and single.

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contradiction)

Answer (score 0):

In the physical sense, things can appear counter (something else), balanced (in equal opposition to something), the negative, the antithesis, the counterform, the complement, exact opposite (Two words, I know.), or maybe evil twin might do. ; )

Depending on the amount of opposition, the protagonist may be left uncommitted, ambivalent, indecisive, hesitant, conflicted, obdurate, and counterbalanced.